# validate subDocuments in a dictionary in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a `userTasteSchema`, with a dictionary field `favorites` composed by
`favoriteSchema` objects. When I save or update a `userTaste`, I want to validate that the elements of the dictionary are valid `favorite` objects. 
Is it possible?
thank you

```
   var userTasteSchema  = new Schema(
        {  
          favorites     : {type: { /* dictionary of favorites */ }, default:{} }
         });

   var favoriteSchema = new Schema(
      {
       name : {type:{String}}
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your model declaration. According to the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) your code should look like:

```
var userTasteSchema  = new Schema(
    {  
      favorites     : [ favoriteSchema ]
     });

var favoriteSchema = new Schema(
  {
   name : {type:String}
   });
```

And that's pretty much it. When you save your parent document, UserTaste, your children validations are run as well. Here is the [reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

> Validation is asynchronously recursive; when you call Model#save,
>   sub-document validation is executed as well. If an error occurs, your
>   Model#save callback receives it

Comment: but in this way, I am creating an array, not a dictionary... doesn't it?

Comment: if you want one to many sub documents relationship, you should create an array, anyway if you do want an object, you can just pass an object, the children schema without the square brackets (from version 4.2.0)